# TransferFrom Error - "not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract Token"

Tags: solidity, remix, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm calling a transfer, transferfrom, approve contract following the open-zeppelin ERC20 source.
I got not found issues. Maybe I'm omitting something.

My Code:

token.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

abstract contract Token is ERC20{}
```

- sample.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "token.sol";

contract TransferToken {
    function transfer() external {
        Token token = Token("sample address here");
        token.transfer(msg.sender, 5);
    }  

    function transferfrom(address recipient, uint amount) external {
        Token token = Token("sample address here");
        token.transferfrom(msg.sender, recipient, amount);
    }

}

contract Owner {
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external {
        Token token = Token("sample address here");
        token.approve("sample address here", amount);

        TransferToken transfertoken = TransferToken("sample address here");
        transfertoken.transfertokenfrom(recipient, amount);
    }
}

The Error:
```

TypeError: Member "transferfrom" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract Token.
--> sample.sol:14:9:
|
14 | token.transferfrom(msg.sender, recipient, amount);
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: You are using `transferfrom` and in the standard it is `transferFrom`. In solidity the case is important.

Comment: It's done now. But I'm still not able to use the functions well. As its giving me gas error

Comment: Please, provide enough information to reproduce the error. How are you deploying the Token contract? It is marked as abstract so you shouldn't be able to deploy it. These errors are quite basic, I'd suggest to follow a tutorial or take a course to learn the basics. It can be frustrating at the beginning.

Comment: Can you suggest any reference to know more?

Comment: I've read nice comments for "Solidity, Blockchain, and Smart Contract Course – Beginner to Expert Python Tutorial" by Patrick Collins. He sometimes answers questions here. There's a new version for javascript developers, but I haven't checked it.